# Javascript/jquery to select values inside two dots in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to find a javascript/jquery code to select the numbers between these dots:

`0373:0081:0D1D:00C4`

I want the output:

```
var A = 0373;
var B = 0081;
var C = 0D1D;
var D = 00C4;
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.split(":")`. Why separate them into four different variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Javascript [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) Method

```
var numberArray = yourString.split(':');
var A = numberArray[0];
var B = numerArray[1];
...
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for, didn't remember the split!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [destructuring assignment:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2fsection%29)

```
var [A, B, C, D] = "0373:0081:0D1D:00C4".split(":");
```

Comment: Very simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the values with the `window` object after splitting.

```js
var string = '0373:0081:0D1D:00C4';

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].forEach(function (v, i) {
    window[v] = this[i];
}, string.split(':'));

console.log(A, B, C, D);
```